# SDL2_mixer failed init on mac (runtime)

Tags: c, macos, sdl-2

having hard time with Sdl2 on mac.
The code compiles well but on runtime Mix_init failed with this error:

```
OGG Support Not Available
```

Strange thing as I installed sdl2_mixer like this:

```
brew install SDL2_mixer --with-libvobis
```

this is the code for initialization

```
int flags = MIX_INIT_OGG;
int initted = Mix_Init(flags);
if ((initted & flags) != flags)
{
    printf("Mix_Init: Failed to init SDL_Mixer\n");
    printf("Mix_Init: %s\n", Mix_GetError());
    MSG_EXIT("Exiting ",1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok , now answers from anyone. looks like it is not a common error.After digging, It seems that SDL2_mixer doesn't work properly on MacOs.
I used SDL2_mixer-1.2 and it is ok. ofcourse i needed to change a little bit of the code.
Fortunatly only initialization needed to be changed. all functions are same in mixer1.2 and mixer2.
However there is some little thing to do.
- remove sdl_mixer if installed
- install some other dependency
-reinstall sdl_mixer
DO NOT REMOVE SDL2_MIXER.
I don't know how it works why I should not remove it, I just realized when I remove it I have other insane error even if i compiled wil -lsdl_mixer and not -lsdl2_mixer.

here are brew commands

```
brew install sdl_mixer --with-libvorbis    
brew uninstall libvorbis libogg //it may ask you de remove sdl_mixer
```

then

```
brew install sdl sdl_image sdl_ttf portmidi hg git
brew reinstall sdl_mixer --with-libvorbis
```

Hope it will help someone else.